Questions about "can you sue / be sued" should automatically be assumed as "can be held up in court"
There is always a comment clarifying that yes in USA you can sue for anything, it's needless, and everyone knows, no one sues with intent of losing so they're asking if it has any credibility to be held in court, and it still kindof means if they can sue as any lawyer would advise them against it if it was destined to be thrown away.
